# level order tree printout bug finding

Tags: tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I implemented level order tree traversal however, it doesn't print out the last two nodes. I am pretty convinced this is a right approach and I want to make this approach work!  Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong in my code?

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

import queue

class Solution:
    def levelOrder(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[List[int]]:        
        q = queue.Queue()
        q.put(root)
        self.level(root, q)

    def level(self, node, q):
        if node == None:
            return
        q.put(node.left)
        q.put(node.right)

        q = self.printyo(q)

        self.level(node.left, q)
        self.level(node.right, q)

    def printyo(self, q):
        if q.empty():
            return
        else:
            node = q.get()
            if node != None:
                print(node.val)
            return q
```

However,

```
Given binary tree [3,9,20,null,null,15,7],
    3
   / \
  9  20
    /  \
   15   7

Above code only prints out 

3
9
20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print the remaining nodes with an extra print (you've added two nodes per function call so you should also print two at some point; it doesn't matter when since you're working with a queue):

```
def level(self, node, q):
    # ... code unchanged

    self.printyo(q)
    self.printyo(q)

    # ... code unchanged
```

Having said that, I'd recommend adjusting your logic to ensure nodes are printed in level-order. Work iteratively or use some construct in your recursion to ensure your queue is populated in a breadth-first manner rather than the depth-first approach you're using here.

Comment: This answer is more accurate. You just need two prints and it doesn't matter where they are; the first one seemed to indicate that it had to be in that particular part of the code, which isn't the case--you'll get the same output either way since you're working with a queue. Does that make sense?